# React.js greater than/Less than in a switch statement

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement, logical-operators

I have taken the breaks out, left one at the bottom, rearranged the order of which case comes first, and have also *switched* between is greater than/less than/etc... With the breaks included, it will either hit the first or last case depending on if you are using "<=" as compared to ">=".

```
constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { clicked: false, windowWidth: window.innerWidth };
        this.welcomeBtn = this.welcomeBtn.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.state.windowWidth);
        const windowCheck = window.innerWidth;
        this.setState({
            windowWidth: windowCheck
        });
    }
 welcomeBtn() {
        console.log(this.state.windowWidth);
        var windowWidthString = this.state.windowWidth;
        switch(true) {
            case (windowWidthString <= 300): 
                window.scrollTo({top: 100, behavior: 'smooth'});
            break;
            case (windowWidthString <= 350): 
                window.scrollTo({top: 1100, behavior: 'smooth'});
            break;
            case (windowWidthString <= 700): 
                window.scrollTo({top: 500, behavior: 'smooth'});
            break;
            case (windowWidthString <= 900): 
                window.scrollTo({top: 900, behavior: 'smooth'});
            break;
            case (windowWidthString <= 1100): 
                window.scrollTo({top: 1100, behavior: 'smooth'});
            break;
        }
    }
  render () {
        return(
            <div>
                <div id="welcomeMessageDiv">
                <h1 className="headTitle">Welcome</h1>
                <button onClick={this.welcomeBtn}>Learn More</button>
                </div>
                <Parallax y={[-20, 20]}>
                  <div>{stuff}<div>
                </Parallax>
                <div id="moreInfoDivHome">
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a `switch` statement here, `if` works just fine:

```js
 welcomeBtn() {
    console.log(this.state.windowWidth);
    var windowWidthString = this.state.windowWidth;

    if (windowWidthString <= 300) { 
        window.scrollTo({top: 100, behavior: 'smooth'});
    }
    else if (windowWidthString <= 350) {
        window.scrollTo({top: 1100, behavior: 'smooth'});
    }
    else if (windowWidthString <= 700) {
        window.scrollTo({top: 500, behavior: 'smooth'});
    }
    else if (windowWidthString <= 900) {
        window.scrollTo({top: 900, behavior: 'smooth'});
    }
    else if (windowWidthString <= 1100) {
        window.scrollTo({top: 1100, behavior: 'smooth'});
    }
    else {
        // handle edge case
    }
}
```

Using `if` works here, because as we traverse down the various checks, we can rule out the window width having a value lower than those values previously checked.

Comment: Thank you, but isnt the whole point of the switch statement so you do not have to write multiple "else if's". To me, using many else ifs instead of a switch statement just seems like bad practice.

Comment: Also I tested this solution, has the same issue as the switch statement. Even at 300px window width, the solution still scrolls 1100px from top as indicated in the last else if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution, although I do not find it eloquent, it does work as intended. I still seek a better solution if one does exist though.

```
welcomeBtn() {
        console.log(this.state.windowWidth);
        var windowWidthString = this.state.windowWidth;
        switch(true) {
            case (windowWidthString >= 300 && windowWidthString <= 499): 
                window.scrollTo({top: 100, behavior: 'smooth'});
            break;
            case (windowWidthString >= 500 && windowWidthString <= 699): 
                window.scrollTo({top: 300, behavior: 'smooth'});
            break;
            case (windowWidthString >= 700 && windowWidthString <= 899): 
                window.scrollTo({top: 500, behavior: 'smooth'});
            break;
            case (windowWidthString >= 900 && windowWidthString <= 1099): 
                window.scrollTo({top: 700, behavior: 'smooth'});
            break;
            case (windowWidthString >= 1100 && windowWidthString <= 2400): 
                window.scrollTo({top: 1100, behavior: 'smooth'});
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is by far less preferable than my answer, as it requires explicitly writing out full ranges for each condition.

Comment: I agree, but I tested your code and ran into the same issue that plagued me with my original switch statement as indicated in my previous comment on your code.